# AWS EMR jupyter error 403 Forbidden (Workspace is not attached to cluster)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have a simple notebook in EMR.   I have no running clusters.  From the notebook open page itself I request a *new* cluster so my expectation is that all params necessary to ensure a good workbook-cluster connection are in place.  I observe that the release is `emr-5.36.0` and that applications Hadoop, Spark, Livy, Hive, JupyterEnterpriseGateway are all included.   I am using default security groups.

Both the cluster and the workbook hosts start but upon opening jupyter (or jupyterlab), the kernel launch fails with the message `Error 403: Workbook is not attached to cluster`.  All attempts at "jiggling" the kernel -- choosing a different one, doing a start/stop, etc. -- all yield the same error.

There are a number of docs plus answers here on SO but these tend to revolve around trying to use EC2 instances instead of EMR, messing with master vs. core nodes, forgetting the JupyterGateway, and the like.   Again, you'd think that a cluster launched *directly* from notebook would work.

Any clues?

Comment: No one?  I tried this on us-east-1 too.   No change.   A raw launch of a notebook -- to create a raw launch of a cluster -- yields `403: Workbook not attached to cluster` .  What part of the "how to" am I missing?   No imports or 3rd party dependencies here; just a blank workbook.   Seems odd, no?   

Teaser:   Bounty soon: but if I find out you're from AWS Solutions, well... I will be disappointed.

Comment: Try `emr-6.9.0` - does that make a difference? And you're using JupyterHub, right?

Comment: emr-6.9.0 is *not* offered as an option in the cluster-create-from-new-notebook use case.   Will try going the other way and start with the 6.9 cluster.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Did not work -- in fact, provisioning the cluster failed, never mind trying to start a notebook:  Terminating:  On the master instance (i-0bea30660d2f9ebc2), application provisioning failed.   Config:
Release label:emr-6.9.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 3.3.3
Applications:Hive 3.1.3, Pig 0.17.0, Hue 4.10.0, JupyterEnterpriseGateway 2.6.0, Spark 3.3.0, Livy 0.7.1, JupyterHub 1.4.1

Comment: Remarkable that even with a bounty there is no concrete answer to what should (likely) be a pilot error on my part.   I have to assume every day 1000s of people create a notebook and start a cluster from there.

Comment: A bounty does not always guarantee an answer! What IAM permissions does your user have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this many times before and it always works, with the create new cluster option, and default security groups are not an issue.

here is an image of one from before:
[image: EMR Cluster settings]

One thing that could cause this error, and which you have not made clear is that it will not let you open it as root. So do not use the root AWS account to create the cluster / notebook. Create and use an IAM user that has permissions to [launch the cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html)

I tried with the admin policy attached.

Comment: Ah!   I always use the root user to do everything.   I will create an IAM user and give that a shot.   +50 could be coming your way.

Comment: That did the trick.   Wow; googling again yields the AWS doc page that in fact explains this (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-notebook-connection-issues/) ... but I only looked at the "cannot attach" explain at the *top* of the doc.   The answer is at the *bottom*, although I probably would still have zoned out on the IAM vs. root login issue.